# MySql error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint when create table

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I altered the table `Company`, modifying the column `Comp_discountrate`. Then, I create table `TQuote`, and there is an error (1215) due to `Comp_discountrate` as a foreign key constraint. Without the last line of the table defininition, it works well. How can I handle this?

```sql
Alter table Company
modify Comp_discountrate double(2,2) not null default '0.4';

create table TQuote(
    Quo_id varchar(7) not null,
    Mem_id varchar(7) not null,
    Quo_date DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    Comp_discountrate double(2,2) not null default '0.4',
    primary key(Quo_id, Mem_id),
    foreign key(Mem_id) references Tuser(Mem_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key(Comp_discountrate) references Company(Comp_discountrate) on update cascade
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a unique index on Company(Comp_discountrate)

Comment: Thank you very much, I add index because I don't want this column be unique and solve the problem.

Comment: While I don't think it is the best practice, I could've sworn MySQL allowed foreign keys to non-unique field(s) as long as they were indexed.

Comment: @Uueerdo That is correct. Any index will do as far as creating the FK constraint is concerned.

Comment: You guys are correct, I made a mistake on ERD design, this column shouldn't be foreign key in my database

Answer (score 0):

Referenced fields must be indexed. Though I would recommend such indices be unique, MySQL does not require them to be (unless using the NDB storage engine).

Comment: You guys are correct, I made a mistake on ERD design, this column shouldn't be foreign key in my database